# return value of library(.) command in R

Tags: r

In R when you want to load a library, call one foo for example, the command is

```
library(foo)
```

Is there a return value for this call indicating success/failure?  I would like to use as follows

```
if library(foo) != 1:
    install.packages("foo")
```

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `Value` section of `?library`:

> Normally library returns (invisibly) the list of attached packages,
>   but TRUE or FALSE if logical.return is TRUE. When called as library()
>   it returns an object of class "libraryIQR", and for library(help=),
>   one of class "packageInfo".

So in your case, you can do:

```
if (!library(foo, logical.return = TRUE))
    install.packages("foo")
```

Comment: Let *me* be the grammar Nazi for once ;)

Comment: thank you this is one (of many) examples in R where a code example is more helpful than the explanation offered in R help